# Lorentz invariance of moving charges

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, inertial-frames

Imagine an octahedron with an electron fixed at each vertex, and with a 7th electron placed at the center.  The central electron is in equilibrium, it experiences a net force of 0 due to symmetry.  Call this inertial frame $K$.

Now suppose you observe this octahedron from an inertial frame moving at velocity $\:-\mathbf v\:$ parallel to one of the axes of the octahedron, i.e. a line through opposite points; call this frame $K'$.  The octahedron seems to be moving with velocity $\:\mathbf v\:$, so experiences a Lorentz contraction in the direction of motion.  Nevertheless, it still seems to have reflective symmetry through the center, so one might expect the central electron to still be stable.

However, the electric force from the electron behind the center is smaller than that from the electron in front, because the effective distance from the first is larger due to the motion.  In other words, it takes the electric field longer to propagate to the center from the trailing electron than it does from the leading electron, so the field is more dispersed.  Therefore it seems that, from the PoV of the moving inertial frame, the central electron will experience a net force backwards, contradicting Lorentz invariance.

My conjectural solution is that the field of the trailing electron is denser that that of the leading one, because the relative speed of the propagation of the field is slower for the first than the second.  This would compensate for the greater distance of propagation.

1. Is my solution correct?
2. Whatever the solution, where in Maxwell's equations is the solution to be found?

P.S.

1. Thanks Ghoster for pointing me to Earnshaw's theorem.  I've changed "stable" to "in equilibrium".
2. I forgot to deal with the magnetic fields generated by motion.  They are irrelevant because the those fields only produce forces orthogonal to the motion, but what is wanted in this scenario is an adjustment to the forces parallel to the motion.
3. By "propagate" I'm referring to the time required for a change in the position of a particle to manifest as a change in the field at a distance.  That does not happen instantaneously.  Btw, given the generation of a changing magnetic field due to the motion, might there not be radiation?
4. Oops.  Conservation of momentum is also violated.  Was ist los?  This may be relevant:
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_gravity
5. Having looked at the Wikipedia entry on Liénard-Weichert, I believe my solution is correct.  My scenario corresponds to a simple case of LW, where the velocity of the source is constant and along a radial line through the observer.  LW computes the effective propagation distance the same way I did, and seems to calculate two density effects: in time and space.  The density effects exactly compensate for the distance variation.

P.P.S.
This question has been marked "homework-like" or "check-my-work", although it is neither.  I was looking for insight into the details of Lorentz invariance, a qualitative understanding of how a moving system, after the Lorentz transform, behaves like the same system at rest.   After being directed to the LW equations,

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential,

I found the following.

1. It is correct to use the retarded position of the source particles for calculating their field.
2. The difference between the position and the current position is compensated for by two field density changes, in time and space.

   - The time density change is represented in the derivation of the LW equations by the expansion of the Dirac delta expression $\delta(t-t_r)$.
   - The space density effect enters when taking the gradient of $\varphi$: it's the factor of the derivative of $|{\mathbf r}(t)-{\mathbf r}(t_r)|$.
3. The cancellation of the effect of the different propagation distance against the two field density changes means that the field *behaves as if* the source were creating the field instantaneously from its present position.  This also means that momentum is conserved, since the forces of two particles acting on each other are equal but opposite.
4. I was wrong to neglect magnetic effects.  While it's true that the magnetic field generated has no *direct* impact on the motions, it has an *indirect* impact in that the changing magnetic field reduces the electric field.  This effect explains the Lorentz contraction: the particles must move closer together in order to have the same effect after reducing the strength of the electric field.  Thus the Lorentz contraction could be viewed as a classical effect predicted by the LW equations, which were derived from purely classical considerations, at least 5 years before Einstein's first paper on relativity.

Comment: *The central electron is stable, it experiences a net force of 0 due to symmetry.* Actually, its equilibrium is *unstable*. See [Earnshaw’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw's_theorem).

Comment: Do you realize that there are magnetic fields and magnetic forces in the other frame?

Comment: *the propagation of the field* Fields of charges in uniform motion do not propagate. A uniformly moving charge doesn’t radiate.

Comment: The distance  between the trailing charge and the leading charge are Lorentz contracted by the same amount, not sure how you concluded that the lagging particle seems further away.

Comment: @Triatticus: Reread my OP.  The difference in propagation distance has nothing to do with the Lorentz contraction.

Comment: I see, if you've learned about the Liénard-Weichert potentials these are the details of the potentials of moving charges.

Comment: Are you saying that Maxwell's equations by themselves don't define the behavior of a system with moving charges?

Comment: The Liénard-Weichert potentials/fields are a particular solution of the maxwells equations.

Comment: I'm thinking that either (1) the Maxwell Eqs contain all that's necessary to explain the moving octahedron, so I'm missing something in Maxwell; or (2), the LW Eqs involve a relativistic correction to Maxwell, in which case perhaps the Maxwell Eqs don't explain the octahedron.  Can you point to the error in my analysis?

Comment: Yes maxwells has everything you need to explain the situation they even have the finite speed of light baked in. You seem to be missing some background on relativistic electrodynamics and special relativity, which is fine but you'd need to tangle with learning the subject of Electrodynamics first then seeing if that answers your question.

Comment: Some people have tried to distinguish between the speed of light and the speed of propagation of a field.  I think they are both $c$, but did Maxwell address the question of the speed of propagation?